# Slow Core Data performance after migration

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, core-data-migration

i've got some strange Core Data issue after performing an lightweight migration - my app for iPad is using a versioned data model, right now i'm migrating to another data model with only one change : adding an attribute to entity. Migration proceeds without any problems, and after process is done I can run app with all data migrated - only problem is that each save request take about 10x more time than before migration.

- i've checked core data logs of migration process - no error listed
- core data logs (sql queries) are the same before and after migration, only much more slower
- i've opened sqlite database in external sqlite viewer - query times from before migration are the same as times after migration.
- i've added NSSQLiteManualVacuumOption for persistent store after migrations, performance of core data gets a little bit better, still much slower that before migration.

Do have any idea what could be going wrong here? How to restore performance from before migration?

Comment: Have you tried a fresh install, setting up the persistent store directly with the new model rather than migrating an old one, to confirm that it's actually the migration? Have you run with `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1` to see exactly what queries are being run by Core Data? If so, did anything there look odd?

Comment: What does Instruments say as to performance?  Where is the slowness?  Do you have a Instruments profile to share?

Comment: @Tommy Yes, running fresh app for current model works fine, also I did investigate com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug - everything there is just the same as from before the migration.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra I didn't use instruments for core data here since it works on simulator only - issue is for now reproducible only on device.

Comment: Can you see any differences between the SQLite file between a clean install and a migration? This isn't something I've ever seen and I suspect you've discovered some sort of bug with Core Data — maybe it bungles migrating an index or something?

Comment: You can and should run Instruments against the device.  That will show you where the problem is. Without looking at Instruments, you are just guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess I've found the solution. I've replaced automatic lightweight migration with very basic custom migration - with just Xcode generated model mapping - now everything works like a charm. Looks like automatic lightweight migration mechanism cannot handle properly model and data of my persistent store, which is strange because I didn't receive any warning or errors.
Thanks for help everyone.